# How to remove downvote after the grace period expired?

Tags: support, down-votes, grace-period

I accidentally cast a downvote which I want to remove ([Computing $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703706/computing-cos-frac-pi7)).  I found about it too late to reverse my vote and am looking for help in what I can do.  The Help desk was no help at all so I turn to the community.

Comment: i have don this too and my remedy was to cast an upvote and leave a comment.

Comment: Related: [Is it alright to do an unnecessary edit so you can change your vote?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/is-it-alright-to-do-an-unnecessary-edit-so-you-can-change-your-vote)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally it is considered that a small edit is permissible for this situation. (I'm pretty sure it was discussed before but couldn't locate the thread.) In the current case the markup of the Mathematica in- and output could definitely be improved. See one of the other answers for a good example.

Once the edit has been approved (it'll have to be reviewed because you have less than 2000 rep) your vote is unlocked.

In general, votes can be reviewed whenever there has been an edit since the vote was cast. This is to promote improving posts and to make votes about the revision of the post they were cast on. (Of course, with the current volume, it is likely that votes will remain in place, but it is good to have the option available.)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried editing but need to await peer review.  I apparently need to keep checking back?

Comment: Once an edit has been processed, your vote is unlocked. I see quid now has done the suggested small formatting improvement (thanks quid :) ), so you should be able to remove the unwanted vote now.